# Is it a bad practice to change the value of an object, bypassing the setter?

Tags: java, oop

That is, I get the object through the get-method. And then change the value. Thus, I do not create a copy of this object, but change the value of the original.

Example with `List`:

```
getMyListFromPojo().addAll(additionalList);
```

This code will change the value in the field `myListFromPojo`! Is this a normal practice?

Comment: That's perfectly fine

Comment: Personally I don't like it but it is used in JavaFX.

Comment: While not illegal, it may be undesired. You can return an immutable list to prevent this. Either guava's `ImmutableList.copyOf()` or java's `Collections.unmodifiableList()`

Comment: It depends. Is the list a part of the representation of the containing object, or just associated with it? If the former, the representation might change, and the containing object might need to know about state changes.

Comment: Any comments on the answers? although your question is closed, you still might accept one of the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a bad practice to change the value of an object, bypassing the setter?

A good API won't allow you to change the value. `getMyListFromPojo()` would return an unmodifiable collection, no one from the outside would be able to alter the value returned.

On the other hand, a POJO class is supposed to be a very simple class. I rarely see POJO methods return something more complex (for instance, a copy or an immutable object) than a reference to a corresponding field.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to achieve with your object, if you need your object to be immutable(except by using some methods provided), then you would need to show a copy of that object(or make it immutable by using methods like `Collections.Immutable`).
To answer your question: it's perfectly fine to modify a list returned by a method(if that is what you want).

Answer (score 1):

> This code will change the value in the field myListFromPojo! Is this a normal practice?

It is your code, thus your decision.

If you want to allow for such things, nicely document that in JavaDoc, and ensure that the underlying List is an `ArrayList` for example that allows any kind of modification.

If, on the other hand, you do **not** want such changes to take place, then nicely document that in JavaDoc, to then ensure that your APIs do not allow for it to happen. For example by making sure that the List instance is actually some sort of ImmutableList.

And note that *both* ways can be legit. It is really up to the person defining the APIs here what is acceptable and what not. Of course, the first premise would be that all things in your API behave in the same way.

Beyond that, such DTOs/Beans are typically meant to only contain values, so updating them is often allowed. But of course, it *can* lead to problems when multiple threads come into play. From a consistency point of view, you are always better off to **forbid** modifications (instead: changes create new objects with new content). But sometimes the performance penalty for doing that might be considered too high.

Answer (score 1):

I would instead write two methods:

- one for adding a single object to the list

```java
    public void addToListFromPojo(Object object) {
        this.myListFromPojo.add(object);
    }
```

- and another one for adding a list of objects to it

```java
    public void addAllToListOfPojo(List<Object> objectList) {
        this.myListFromPojo.addAll(objectList);
    }
```

That would result in more (theoretically unnecessary) code, but it would support readability and
**keep the responsibility of changing the fields inside the class**.

> If you don't care for responsibilities of units of your code, then just use less code ==> your example

Comment: eventually, it might clutter the class with all Collection's add-remove methods

Comment: @AndrewTobilko sure, this an example of one of the options and not a perfect idea, just one that keeps responsibilities.